# RabbitMq Clustering

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

I am new to RabbitMq. I am not able to understand the concept here. Please find the scenario.

I have two machines (RMQ1, RMQ2) where I have installed rabbitmq in both the machines which are running. Again I clustered RMQ2 to join RMQ1

```
cmd:/> rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@RMQ1
```

If you see the status of the machines here it is as below

In RMQ1

```
c:/> rabbitmqctl cluster_status
    Cluster status of node rabbit@RMQ1...
    [{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@RMQ1,rabbit@RMQ2]}]},
     {running_nodes,[rabbit@RMQ1,rabbit@RMQ2]}]
```

In RMQ2

```
c:\> rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@RMQ2 ...
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@RMQ1,rabbit@RMQ2]}]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@RMQ1,rabbit@RMQ2]}]
```

The in order to publish and subscribe message I am connecting to RMQ1. Now I see the whenever I sent or message to RMQ1, I see message mirrored in both RMQ1 and RMQ2. This I understand clearly that as both the nodes are in same cluster they are getting mirrored across nodes.

Let say I bring down the RMQ2, I still see message getting published to RMQ1.

But when I bring down the RMQ1, I cannot publish the message anymore. From this I understand that RMQ1 is master and RMQ2 is slave.

Now I have below questions, without changing the code :

1. How do I make the RMQ2 take up the job of accepting the message.
2. What is the meaning of Highly Available Queues.
3. How should be the strategy for implementing this kind scenario.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Question #2 is best answered first, since it will clear up a lot of things for you.

**What is the meaning of highly available queues?**

A good source of information for this is [the Rabbit doc on high availability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html). It's very important to understand that mirroring (which is how you achieve high availability in Rabbit) and clustering are not the same thing. You need to create a cluster in order to mirror, but mirroring doesn't happen automatically just because you create a cluster.

When you cluster Rabbit, the nodes in the cluster share exchanges, bindings, permissions, and other resources. This allows you to manage the cluster as a single logical broker and utilize it for scenarios such as load-balancing. However, even though queues in a cluster are accessible from any machine in the cluster, each queue and its messages are still actually located only on the single node where the queue was declared.

This is why, in your case, bringing down RMQ1 will make the queues and messages unavailable. If that's the node you always connect to, then that's where those queues reside. They simply do not exist on RMQ2.

In addition, even if there are queues and messages on RMQ2, you will not be able to access them unless you specifically connect to RMQ2 after you detect that your connection to RMQ1 has been lost. Rabbit will not automatically connect you to some surviving node in a cluster.

By the way, if you look at a cluster in the RabbitMQ management console, what you see might make you think that the messages and queues are replicated. They are not. You are looking at the *cluster* in the management console. So regardless of which node you connect to in the console, you will see a cluster-wide view.

So with this background now you know the answer to your other two questions:

**What should be the strategy for implementing high availability? / how to make RMQ2 accept messages?**

From your description, you are looking for the failover that high availability is intended to provide. You need to enable this on your cluster. This is done through a policy, and there are various ways to do it, but the easiest way is in the management console on the Admin tab in the Policies section:

[image]

[The previously cited doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) has more detail on what it means to configure high availability in Rabbit.

What this will give you is mirroring of queues and messages across your cluster. That way, if RMQ1 fails then RMQ2 will still have your queues and messages since they are mirrored across both nodes.

An important note is that Rabbit will not automatically detect a loss of connection to RMQ1 and connect you to RMQ2. Your client needs to do this. I see you tagged your question with `EasyNetQ`. EasyNetQ provides this "failover connect" type of feature for you. You just need to supply both node hosts in the connection string. The [EasyNetQ doc on clustering](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Cluster-Support) has details. Note that EasyNetQ even lets you inject a simple load balancing strategy in this case as well.